# Proof that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot \log(\frac{x+1}{x+10})$ is $-9$

Tags: limits, logarithms

Given this limit:

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot \log\left(\frac{x+1}{x+10}\right) $$

I may use this trick:

$$ \frac{x+1}{x+1} = \frac{x+1}{x} \cdot \frac{x}{x+10} $$

So I will have:

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot \left(\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right) + \log\left(\frac{x}{x+10}\right)\right)  = $$
$$ = 1 + \lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot \log\left(\frac{x}{x+10}\right) $$

But from here I am lost, I still can't make it look like a fondamental limit. How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting $h=\frac1x$ and assuming Natural Logarithm

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\cdot \ln \frac{x+1}{x+10} =\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln\frac{1+h}{1+10h}}h$$

$$\text{As }\ln_e \frac ab=\ln_e a-\ln_e b, \ln\frac{1+h}{1+10h}=\ln(1+h)-\ln(1+10h)$$

$$\implies \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln\frac{1+h}{1+10h}}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)-\ln(1+10h)}h$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}h-10\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+10h)}{10h} $$

Do you know, $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}x=??$$

Comment: May I request to disclose the mistake here?

Comment: Go for it! $\textbf{}$

Comment: @Potato, if you have down-voted, please pinpoint the mistake

Comment: I did not! I thought you meant that you had discovered a mistake, and I was inviting you to fix it. The answer seems correct to me and I have upvoted it.

Comment: @Potato, thanks for the feedback. But, I'm keen to know my mistake here. Because, if there is something wrong, reader(s) will also be affected by that

Comment: I do not think there is a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x+10}\right)
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\left(1-\frac{9}{x+10}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{9}{x+10}\right)}{-\frac{9}{x+10}}\left(-\frac{9x}{x+10}\right)\\[9pt]
&=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\log(1+u)}{u}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(-\frac{9x}{x+10}\right)\\[9pt]
&=1\cdot(-9)\\[18pt]
&=-9
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

I'll use the *famous* limit
$$\left(1+\frac{a}{x+1}\right)^x\approx\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x\to e^a$$

We have
$$x \ln \frac{x+1}{x+10}=x \ln \frac{x+1}{x+1+9}=-x\ln\left( 1+\frac{9}{x+1} \right)=-\ln\left( 1+\frac{9}{x+1} \right)^x\to-9$$

Answer (score 0):

By the Lagrange mean value theorem, for $0<a\le b$, we have
$$
\frac{b-a}{b}\le\log(b)-\log(a)\le\frac{b-a}{a}
$$
So,
$$
L(x)=x\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x+10}\right)=-x\log\left(\frac{x+10}{x+1}\right)=
-x(\log(x+10)-\log(x+1))\\
\implies -9\frac{x}{x+10}\le L(x)\le -9\frac{x}{x+1}
$$
which shows $L(x)\stackrel{x \to \infty}{\to} -9$, by the squeeze principle (theorem).